# Excel : Find only Hexa decimals from 1 cell

Tags: excel

I'm a newbie on Excel. 
So I have a list of some names ending with Hexa decimals. And some names, that doesn't have any.
My mission is to see only those names with Hexa decimals. (Mabye somehow filter them out)

Column:

```
BFAXSPOINTDEVBAUHOFLAN2AD
BFAXSQLBAUHOFLAN207
BFAXSQLDEVBAUHOFLAN27A
BFREPDEVBAUHOFLAN258
BFREPORTINGBAUHOFLAN20B
COBALTSEA02900
COBALTSEAVHOST900
DIRECTO8000
DIRECTO9000
DIRECTODCDIRECTOLA009
DYNAMAEBSSISE006
SURVEYEBSSISE006
KVMSRV00",
KVMSRV01",
KVMSRV02",
ASR
CACTI
DBSYNC",
DTV
```

and so on...

Comment: "D" is a hexadecimal. Does that mean that, for example, "DEUTSCHLAND" would form part of your desired list?

Comment: Yes to answer properly you need to understand what a Hexidecimal is; there are many 'valid' hexes in your list which I expect you would consider errors. A hexidecimal is simply a number represented by the characters 0-9 + A-F. That means any subset of characters consisting of those numbers/letters is a 'valid' hexidecimal.

Answer (score 1):

The Function HEX2DEC will help you achieve what you want - it attempts to convert a number as a hexidecimal, into a decimal. If it is not a valid Hex input, it will produce an error.

The key is understanding how many digits you expect your decimal to be - is it the last 5 characters; the last 10; etc. Also note that there is a risk that random text / numbers will be seen as hexidecimal when really that's not what it represents [but that's a problem with the question as you have laid it out; going solely based on the text provided, all we can see is whether a particular cell creates a valid Hexidecimal].

The full formula would look like this[assuming your data starts in A1, and that your Hexidecimal numbers are expected to be 6 characters long, this goes in B1 and is copied down]:

```
=ISERROR(HEX2DEC(RIGHT(A1,6)))
```

This takes the 6 rightmost characters of a cell, and attempts to convert it from Hex to Decimal. If it fails, it will produce TRUE [because of ISERROR]; if it succeeds, it will produce FALSE.

Then simply filter on your column to see the subset of results you care about.

Comment: Even restricting to 6-character cases, "DECADE" is a valid hexadecimal, though a perfectly valid word in the English language to boot.

Comment: Exactly - and to further press the point with data in the data table provided, all numerical data is a valid hexidecimal, meaning the only thing that this 'check' actually does reliably is eliminate strings which contain symbols / letters higher than F. It has many chances for false positives; for manual review it may be sufficient but further information on what constitutes a 'valid' entry should really be gathered. ie: saying the entries ending '009' are invalid hexidecimal because they dont contain letters is like saying that 54 is not a valid number as it doesnt contain the numbers 8 or 9.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following *UDF*:

```
Public Function EndsInHex(r As Range) As Boolean
   Dim s As String, CH As String
   s = r(1).Text
   CH = Right(s, 1)
   If CH Like "[A-F]" Or CH Like "[0-9]" Then
      EndsInHex = True
   Else
      EndsInHex = False
   End If
End Function
```

[image]

*For the string to end in a hex, the last character must be a hex.*